# I want to use iAd in my game but it says that it cannot cast value of type UIView to SKView

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

```
  @IBOutlet weak var Banner: ADBannerView!

      override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

         Banner.hidden = true
         Banner.delegate = self
         self.canDisplayBannerAds = true

         // configure the view

         let skView = view as! SKView
         skView.multipleTouchEnabled = false

         // Create and configure the scene
         scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
         scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

         // Present the scene
         skView.presentScene(scene)
      }
```

the problem is at `let skView = View as! SKView`

When I start the game it just crashes immediately but when I'm coding it's not telling me there is an error.

Comment: By the way, [*"The iAd App Network will be discontinued as of June 30, 2016."*](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01152016a).

Answer (score 0):

It is crashing because your view is not an SKView,  how did you set this up?  If it is a xib file, you need to make sure that the custom class is set to SKView

Comment: sorry im a beginner what is a xib file ?

Comment: it is probably a storyboard in your case,  xib is the file format for view controllers